# how to read an XML file that contains many "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" with QXmlStreamReader?

Tags: c++, xml, qt

After creating the xml file with QXmlStreamWriter, I am trying to add each modification of parameters at the end of the file, and I do  startDocument in each addition, how can I read an XML file that contains many of

Help please please !

Comment: That is not a valid XML file. There can only be one `<?xml ?>` block, at the top of the file.  If you want multiple complete documents in a single file, you have to delimit them, and then split the file on that delimiter when reading each individual document.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to read the old data first, alter it and replace the whole file without adding a whole "new document"?

Comment: I would qualify Remy Lebeau's answer a little. An XML document is a sequence of octets. There's nothing in the spec to say you can't have multiple such sequences in a single file, and a parser that was able to handle this (e.g. by guaranteeing to leave the input stream open and positioned at the right place after parsing a document) would be entirely conformant. But I don't know of any XML parser that offers such an API/guarantee. So you're on your own.

Comment: thank you for your responses, here is an example of xml file where I save my data: as you see <NUMERO_SLICE> block repeats with each addition of new parameters. Normally this block is added before the </ Fiche_Du_Patient> but I have not found a way with QXmlStreamWriter (I am a beginner in xml) I searched the net, I found nothing

is it exist, please, a method that adds the <NUMERO_SLICE> block each time before </ Fiche_Du_Patient>?

cordially

Comment: how I can put my file in this field?please

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually convert the document from your custom format of multiple-concatenated XML files back into real, stand-alone XML files, then pass it into the parser once it is in fact valid XML data.